# How to use axios from react front end to get object from nodejs on component load (useEffect)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have the following setup below and what i am trying to do is get allQuestions (an object) from nodejs backend and set its state to the questions state. console.log(data) shows my desired response but setQuestion(data) and console.log(question) returns an empty object. meaning set question hasnt worked. and my intention is to map through the question object after setting new state.

```
const Questions = (props) => {

  const [question, setQuestion] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/questions`)
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data.allQuestions;
      console.log(data);
      setQuestion(data);
      console.log(question);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
  });

  },[]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setQuestion` is an async call, meaning that it won't update right away. Instead of doing `console.log(question)` right after setting the state, you should do this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(question);
  },[question]);
```

This useEffect will be run once question is actually changed.

Comment: Glad I could help